# How do I get the black Google toolbar back?

Tags: google-search

Suddenly a couple of days ago the toolbar disappeared when accessing Google like (btw. I am already logged to my Google account, so that's not a problem):

```
http://google.com
```

I am using Google Chrome latest version:

**Version 25.0.1364.172 m**

I use a lot of translate or images Google sub pages and other functions from that bar and it comes very handy to have them there.

However, now when I want to access the Google search page I need to type directly:

```
http://translate.google.com
```

Is there a way to set Google black toolbar to appear on every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug has been posted on the [Chromium bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=200602) on this issue, apparently it was a deliberate move by Google:

> This is a deliberate Search experiment on Chrome v27, and not a bug. 
>   Thanks for the report, though!
>
> **Status**: WontFix

And later:

> I understand your frustration, but just to be clear, Chrome is not
>   changing the google.com webpage.  This is a Google Search experiment
>   you happen to be in that has nothing to do with Chrome code.

So the only work around at this point would be to use a different browser or downgrade your Chrome install. Alternatively, if Translate is the only thing you are missing maybe a [bookmark](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95739) would serve as a replacement?

Comment: Thanks, I am using Firefox for webdev, but I have permanently disbaled cache to display all changes in code properly. So, it is slower than chrome, obviously. And I am too lazy to toggle it all the time ;) and having open another browser when I don't need it is a little too much I guess. Anyway, I will need to change my habits I guess ;) Thanks for your answer and I hope Google will go back in this case to the black top bar, at least in my testing group.

Comment: Wow, I have it back :D. Big brother is watching/listening ;D. However, in this case it's nice.

Comment: Glad you got things back! If you want to disable caching on Firefox, check out [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) toolbar, it provides an option to easily disable/enable cache - along with dozens of other handy tools.

Comment: Yes, I know ;) I am using it all the time. But I was forgetting to turn it on off, so I decided to use chrome to casual browsing and firefox for webdev about a year and a half ago or so.